# SQL Server Management Studio, Using Running Total can i Override final value to a minimum amount

Tags: sql-server, overriding

I have running total to help office calculate total Storage cost of options, however we have an overall minimum value of $200.00 for any storage costs, is there a way to override the final value of the Running Total be the minimum ?

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
    o.order_no, d.item_no, d.[desc], i.u_storage, 
    SUM (I.U_STORAGE) OVER (ORDER BY D.SEQ_NO) AS RunningTotal
FROM
    ordhdr o 
INNER JOIN
    orddet d ON o.order_no = d.order_no 
INNER JOIN
    item i ON i.item_no = d.item_no 
WHERE
    o.order_no = 'q160542' 
    AND i.u_storage > 0 
ORDER BY 
    d.seq_no
```

Here is my current output, I would like the final number of 153.00 to jump to 200.00

```
order_no    item_no             desc                 u_storage  RunningTotal
Q160542   ECONTAINERBIN         Container Bin w/lid     31.50   31.50
Q160542   ECONTAINERBIN         Container Bin w/lid     31.50   63.00
Q160542   ELED-36WRMUC          LED 36"" Sierra         37.50   100.50
Q160542   ELED-SM50             LED Snowman  Insta      52.50   153.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a conditional expression (or `greatest()` if your database supports that):

```
select o.order_no, d.item_no, d.[desc], i.u_storage, 
       (case when sum(I.U_STORAGE) over (order by D.SEQ_NO) < 200 and
                  max(d.seq_no) over () = d.seqno
             then 200
             else sum(I.U_STORAGE) over (order by D.SEQ_NO)
        end) AS RunningTotal
from ordhdr o inner join
     orddet d
     on o.order_no = d.order_no inner join
     item i
     on i.item_no = d.item_no 
where o.order_no = 'q160542' and
      i.u_storage > 0 
order by d.seq_no
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you it worked perfectly! Greatly appreciated